# What is this character from a neo-Confucian commentary?

Tags: characters, character-identification

I cannot identify this character anywhere in my dictionaries.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a variant of 概 as in 大概

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“槩” (u+69e9) is a variant of character “概”

https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QjAxNzgzLTAwMg

quite common in older / ancient editions of books